# Trying to convert a method from a string into an integer

Tags: c#, methods

I'm writing a program that will count the amount of commas a string the user wrote contains.

I'm doing this by using another method in which the written string gets analyzed and the amount of commas are returned.

The problem I'm having is that I'm using a string, which needs to be  converted into an integer while sitting in a method, if that makes sense.

I know this can be done easier by just removing the method and writing the code in the 'main', but I don't want to since I will be expanding the program to also analyze the amount of full stops and the amount of semicolons in the written string.

Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a text:");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        int count = 0;
        count = NumberOfCommas(text);
        int kommaCount = count;


        int NumberOfCommas(int text1)
        {
            foreach (char letter in text)
            {
                if (letter == ',' )
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("There's {0} comma(s) in your text.", kommaCount);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The error code I'm getting is "cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'. (the code is referencing to the 'text' part of this line: `count = NumberOfCommas(text);`)

I hope I explained it well, so my question is: how do I fix this?

Comment: Hello there your method parameter is `int` but you pass a `string` as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your method signature.
`int NumberOfCommas(int text1)` is looking for `int text1` and it should be `string text1`.

Also, I'd like to point out two things.  First, you're using a local function.  There's nothing wrong with that and for what you're doing here it's fine.  I might suggest pulling it out since it really doesn't have any variables that require it to stay scoped to the method.

Another thing is your point about thinking others would prefer you to place it all in `main` but you said

> I will be expanding the program

so you decided against it... 
This is a good thing and the correct way of thinking / development so if someone tells you to put it in main for simplicity I tell you stick to your guns.  You're logic is right.

Answer (score 1):

Change the function signature to

```
 int NumberOfCommas(string text1) { ...
```

Also move this function out of the `main` function.

Comment: This helped! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a text:");
    string text = Console.ReadLine();
    int count = 0;
    count = NumberOfCommas(text);

    Console.WriteLine("There's {0} comma(s) in your text.", count);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

int NumberOfCommas(String text1)
{
    int count;

        foreach (char letter in text1)
        {
            if (letter == ',' )
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
}
```

There were several errors. Parameter data type to the function should be String, text in foreach loop should be text1. And you do not need to count variables.